# How to determine if user manually unpaired device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Suppose a user goes into the ios Settings app and unpairs a BLE device. It's a central device whose services are known, including encrypted ones. Is there a way to find out programmatically in peripheral app that the user has unpaired the device?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the documentation on the developer site yet?

Answer (score 0):

ExternalAccessory framework has delegate method

```
optional func accessoryDidDisconnect(_ accessory: EAAccessory)
```

which informs app about disconnection of external accessory but BLE device has be signed for Apple MFi Program